# Create a new User Specific Page or Post when they register

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to create a new page or post when a user registers in my `wordpress website`. And I want it to keep its access specific to that user and noone else. Is there a pluggin for the same? If not, can anyone just hint me to add user specific encryption php function to that page? Like the params and everything.

Comment: there are plugin to create user profile. if that is not your goal. you can use 'user_register' hook and use 'wp_insert_post()' function there to create a post. to make created post available only to that user you should compare post_author of post with get_current_user_id() when that post is requested.

Comment: I see thanks. But how do I embed this as Meta description of that post? So that everytime I could check for this condition.

Comment: ywc, wp_insert_post() returns created post's id on success, use that id with update_post_meta() function to flag that post sth like: update_post_meta($post_id , 'owner_user' , $register_user_id); | another way is to just pass wp_insert_post with post_author set as registered user id  . i can post an answer with code if you want

Comment: wordpress.org has detailed docs for all the hooks and functions i mentioned